# change viewcontroller in the storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios5, mapkit, storyboard

there is problem, I want use alloutAccessoryControlTapped method to change viewcontroller. but it doesn't works. here is my code:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    NSLog(@"calloutAccessoryControlTapped");
    Restaurant *location = [view annotation];


//    RestaurantDetail *resdetail = [[RestaurantDetail alloc] init];
    RestaurantDetail *resdetail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"details"];
    [resdetail setLocation:location];
    [self.view addSubview:resdetail.view];

}
```

I used storyboard to build the view. this code runs well in old vison. but I want try to use storyboard. unfortunately, it doesn't work. anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You might have more luck if you create a named segue from one viewcontroller to the other and trigger it here. I think that does more behind-the-scenes stuff (that you *could* do manually, but I don't know what all that is off-hand).

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MyNamedSegue" sender:sender];
```